# i am having trouble to run a query on every page load, how do i make one query which works on all views?

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble to make a query which works on all pages, like to get ip address of user on each page of website they visit with url. As of now i am putting this query on each controller.

```
**controller:**

  public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $ip = $request->ip();
        $userDetail = Location::get($ip);

        $visitor = new Visitor;
        $visitor->ip = $userDetail->ip;
        $visitor->url = url()->full();

        $visitor->save();
        return view('index');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers). This will run on every invocation of your application.

Within that service provider, you'll run the query and use [`View::share`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) to share it to all Blade views.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a helper file like: helper.php and set   the path in composer.json in autoload part like this:

```
"files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ],
```

then inside helprt.php
create your function like : myfunction() and use it in all of your project.